# Parsley: Radio "Object 73 has no method 'replace'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

I'm trying to integrate **parsley.js** to my dynamic from. When I click the submit button which triggers an event in the javascript I call

```
var validateForm = $('#myForm').parsley().validate();
```

But it wont work since in the console theres an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 73 has no method 'replace'

Object 73 seems to be the radiobutton field (I guess - correct me if it isnt that). Generated it looks like this:

```
<span class="formw">
   Test1<input class="formField data-parsley-required" prop="text" type="radio" name="73" value="Test1" data-parsley-multiple="73" data-parsley-id="0256">
   Test2<input class="formField " prop="text" type="radio" name="73" value="Test2" data-parsley-multiple="73">
   Test3<input class="formField " prop="text" type="radio" name="73" value="Test3" data-parsley-multiple="73">
 </span>
```

I really dont know how I can get parsley to work in my form and fix this replace error...

any help would be appreciated!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I suppose Parsley don't support `data-parsley-multiple` or `name` that are pure numbers. It tries to make a str.replace() and this is not a string.

Try to use a string instead, like `data-parsley-multiple="radio73"`

Best

Comment: thanks for your answer beside all the negative votes! Now I realized that the problem is the number in the name. Sadly I can't change that, because in the backend I need these values in the name, otherwise I would need to change the whole logic. But really appreciate your answer! Looks like I have to look for something else beside parsely :)

Comment: Maybe you need to keep 73 for the id or the name. Fine. But **nothing** in the backend force you to keep that value for data-parsley-multiple. You can set your own data-parsley-multiple value to your inputs and then call parsley

Comment: With "in the backend" I meant to say my logic for my application which is in the backend and not the parsley backend, I'm sorry if I didnt express it clear enough. thanks anyway :)